# Optimizing pagination in function-based views (in Django)

Tags: django, django-views, django-pagination

In a class-based Django `listview`, when one allots a value to `paginate_by`, it ensures that the `object_list` available in `get_context_data` method is limited to **only those objects that are needed for that particular page**.

E.g. `get_queryset` might return 1000 objects, but if a single page is to show 20 objects, then only 20 objects are available as `object_list` in `get_context_data`. This is a good optimization when dealing with large querysets.

How can one create this same behavior in function-based views? Under typical implementation (and taking the aforementioned example), all 1000 objects would be evaluated and then used in pagination. That means that in this particular case, CBVs are definitively better than function-based views. Can function-based views provide the same functionality? An illustrative example would be great (or a 'no they can't' kind of answer works too).

---

Here's the actual CBV:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 20
    template_name = "post_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return all_posts()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        posts = retrieve_posts(context["object_list"]) #retrieves 20 posts
        return context
```

Here's the actual FBV:

```
def post_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = PostListForm()
    context = {}
    obj_list = all_posts()
    posts = retrieve_posts(obj_list) #retrieves 1000 posts
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 20)
    page = request.GET.get('page', '1')
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

the `retrieve_posts()` function:

```
def retrieve_posts(post_id_list):
    my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
    posts = []
    pipeline1 = my_server.pipeline()
    for post_id in post_id_list:
        hash_name="pt:"+str(post_id)
        pipeline1.hgetall(hash_name)
    result1 = pipeline1.execute()
    count = 0
    for hash_obj in result1:
        posts.append(hash_obj)
        count += 1
    return posts
```

the `all_posts()` function:

```
def all_posts():
    my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
    return my_server.lrange("posts:1000", 0, -1) #list of ids of 1000 posts
```

---

Difference in response times of the two approaches (via newrelic):

[image]

The blue part is processing of the view.

Comment: Hello Hassan, you seem to have got that view right. What seems to be problem?

Comment: Hey @e4c5. My objects being retrieved are redis hashes. In the class-based view, the context is limited to 20 objects (thanks to `paginate_by`), whereas in the FBV, I end up executing the retrieval for the entire 1000 object list. As a result, server response time is double for my FBV, compared to the CBV.

Comment: Can you put the absolute timings for the two methdos and also post the retrieve_object_list method

Comment: @e4c5: added the code snippets. I realized the examples I had originally posted were too simplified and missed important nuances. More accurate code is posted now. Notice how I'm only retrieving 20 objects in the CBV, whereas the full host of objs is retrieved in the FBV. How ought I rewrite my FBV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `retreive_posts` with the original object list. Use the page's object list after paginating.

```
posts = retrieve_posts(page.obj_list)
```

Comment: Big things have small beginnings. Thanks for this insight.